# Customized HTTP to HTTPS redirect with drupal multisite

Tags: redirection, multi-sites, ssl

I have a multisite setup with drupal 7.23 which is working fine. Websites are like this:

SITE1

- http:// www.site1.info

SITE2 and 2 subdomains

- https:// www.site2.com
- https:// sub1.site2.com
- https:// sub2.site2.com

SITE3

- https:// www.site3.com

As you can see site2 and site3 are full SSL anabled but for site1 I have only some pages with SSL like this:

NO SSL:

- http:// www.site1.info
- http:// www.site1.info/page1

SSL:

- https:// www.site1.info/page2
- https:// www.site1.info/page2/subpage1

I have enabled non www. to www. redirect which drupal is offering by default and adjusted it a bit:

```
RewriteEngine on

  # I've also added these 2 lines to redirect HTTP to HTTPS because the next 3 lines didn't worked.
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|sub1|sub2)\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

BUT here is where I'm stuck:
if I access for instance: https://www.site1.info it s not redirected to http://www.site1.info and keep SSL ony for the desired pages.
I'm not sure how to write all these rewrite rules given the fact that I'm no htaccess expert.

Comment: Please don't use code blocks for things that are not code. And by the way, I don't quite understand your needs, but go have a look on [Secure Pages](https://drupal.org/project/securepages) module.

Comment: Ok, perhaps I should explain better situation for site1. As I said only some of the pages need ssl, not the whole site. So i only need to redirect those pages and not all website but also not interfere with site2 and site3. I was thinking this could be done in .htaccess without installing an extra module.

Comment: @tenken look at the [revision history](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/89237/revisions) of the question. See the [revision that was](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/89237/1) in place when I posted my comment. Then you will see I was *not* talking about Apache conf.

Comment: I would tell you to check out the htaccess module but they don't have multisite options. These are the only options: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK7X8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK7X8.png)

Comment: Apache rewrites has little to do with Drupal. You should ask this on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about server settings that aren't influenced by Drupal.